# Click to expand all clickable elements inside a website by Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect and save all the links that are inside the called tags `href` that are always on this path of elements:

```
<td class="score-time score">
    <a href="/matches/2021/07/26/nc-america/concacaf-gold-cup/costa-rica/canada/3506351/" class=" ">0 - 2</a>
```

[image]

The script I'm using is this:

```
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://int.soccerway.com/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
jogos = soup.find_all("td", class_="score-time score")

with open("Lista_de_Links.csv", "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    titlemenu = "label"
    f.write(titlemenu)
    for tag in jogos:
        linkslist = tag.find("a", href=True)["href"]

        row = linkslist + "\n"
        f.write(row)
```

The problem is that in this model I can't get the values that are hidden because of the elements that need to be expanded from a link in order to access them:

[image]

I'm trying to create a template so I can click all the buttons to expand and only then collect the links, but the button isn't expanding even using the `.click`, I would like some help to understand how I need to use it so that my need is met.

Element clickable:

```
<tr class="group-head  clickable ">
```

My script trying to clicks:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = r"C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(r"http://int.soccerway.com/")

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='group-head  clickable']")
link.click()
```

Comment: By chance can you show the HTML?

Comment: Hello mate @dio , the url is in both scripts, the html is too long to publish here in the question. Sorry for not publishing, but question analysts would complain about the size of the data included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = (x.a['href'] for x in soup.select('td.score-time.score'))
    print(list(goal))


main('https://us.soccerway.com/')
```

Output:

```
['/matches/2021/07/26/nc-america/concacaf-gold-cup/costa-rica/canada/3506351/', '/matches/2021/07/26/nc-america/concacaf-gold-cup/united-states-of-america/jamaica/3506352/']
```

Updated Answer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = get_soup(r.text)
        goal = ((num, x['id'].split('-', 1)[-1]) for num, x in enumerate(
            soup.select('tr[id^=date_matches]'), start=1))

        for n, m in goal:
            params = {
                "block_id": "block_home_matches_31",
                "callback_params": json.dumps({
                    "block_service_id": "home_index_block_homematches",
                    "date": "2021-07-26",
                    "display": "all",
                    "stage-value": n
                }),
                "action": "showMatches",
                "params": json.dumps({
                    "competition_id": m
                })
            }
            r = req.get(
                'https://us.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches', params=params)
            soup = get_soup(r.json()['commands'][0]['parameters']['content'])
            res = (x.a['href'] for x in soup.select('td.score-time'))
            print(list(res))


main('https://us.soccerway.com/')
```

Output:

```
['/matches/2021/07/26/nc-america/concacaf-gold-cup/costa-rica/canada/3506351/', '/matches/2021/07/26/nc-america/concacaf-gold-cup/united-states-of-america/jamaica/3506352/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/africa/cecafa-senior-challenge-cup/ethiopia-u23/eritrea-under-23/3567660/', '/matches/2021/07/26/africa/cecafa-senior-challenge-cup/uganda-under-23/congo-dr-under-23/3567667/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/primera-division/estudiantes-de-la-plata/ca-independiente/3528747/', '/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/primera-division/ca-talleres-cordoba/arsenal-de-sarandi/3528749/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/prim-b-nacional/deportivo-maipu/asociacion-atletica-estudiantes/3564124/', '/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/prim-b-nacional/club-atetico-atlanta/club-atletico-chacarita-juniors/3564131/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/prim-d-metro/barracas-bolivar/argentino-de-rosario/3502592/', '/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/prim-d-metro/deportivo-yupanqui/defensores-de-cambaceres/3502595/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/argentina/reserve-league/velez-sarsfield-res/defensa-y-justicia-res/3565713/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/australia/victoria-division-one/kingston-city/manningham-united-blues/3435468/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/australia/victoria-womens-premier-league/australia-fc-bulleen-lions/senior-ntc/3435562/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/bangladesh/b-league/bangladesh-police/mohammedan-sc/3500557/', '/matches/2021/07/26/bangladesh/b-league/sheikh-jamal-dhanmondi-club/abahani-ltd/3500558/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/bolivia/lfpb/real-santa-cruz-bol/club-deportivo-san-jose/3544580/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/serie-a/sport-club-do-recife/ceara-sporting-club/3482032/', '/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/serie-a/esporte-clube-juventude/associacao-chapecoense-kindermannmastervet/3482034/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/serie-b/avai-futebol-clube/gremio-esportivo-brasil/3482998/', '/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/serie-b/sampaio-correa-futebol-clube/clube-de-regatas-brasil/3483000/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/mineiro-ii/esporte-clube-democrata/ipatinga-futebol-clube/3507261/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/brazil/cbf-brasileiro-u20/gremio-fb-porto-alegrense-u20/sc-internacional-u20/3520264/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/bulgaria/a-pfg/pfk-botev-vraca/fk-arda-kardzhali/3520723/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/bulgaria/b-pfg/bulgaria-fk-minyor-pernik/ludogorets-ii/3520734/', '/matches/2021/07/26/bulgaria/b-pfg/etar/levski-lom/3520735/', '/matches/2021/07/26/bulgaria/b-pfg/pfc-montana-1921/cska-1948-sofia-ii/3520739/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/canada/plsq/mont-royal-outremont/blainville/3528616/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/chile/primera-division/cd-universidad-catolica/ohiggins/3478519/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/chile/segunda-division/colina/club-deportivo-general-velasquez-s-a/3519280/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/china-pr/china-league-one/anhui-litian/beijing-hongdeng/3545188/', '/matches/2021/07/26/china-pr/china-league-one/beijing-institute-of-technology/zhejiang-lucheng/3545189/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/colombia/primera-a/corporacion-popular-deportiva-junior/envigado-futbol-club/3554518/', '/matches/2021/07/26/colombia/primera-a/deportivo-cali/corporacion-deportiva-independiente-medellin/3554517/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/colombia/primera-b/union-magdalena/juventud-soacha/3553299/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/colombia/colombia-liga-femenina/santa-fe/colombia-cd-la-equidad-seguros-sa/3530168/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/curacao/curacao-sekshon-paga/crksv-jong-holland/rkv-fc-sithoc/3521947/', '/matches/2021/07/26/curacao/curacao-sekshon-paga/rksv-centro-dominguito/sv-centro-social-deportivo-barber/3521948/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/denmark/superliga/sonderjyske/vejle-boldklub-elitefodbold-as/3510679/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/ecuador/primera-a/barcelona-sporting-club-guayaquil/manta-futbol-club/3454011/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/egypt/premier-league/asyouty-sport/national-bank-of-egypt/3501429/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/estonia/ii-liiga/kuressaare-ii/fc-kose-/3507923/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/faroe-islands/1-deild/b36-torshavn-ii/vikingur-gotu-ii/3466575/', '/matches/2021/07/26/faroe-islands/1-deild/skala-itrottarfelag/nsi-runavik-ii/3466576/', '/matches/2021/07/26/faroe-islands/1-deild/hb-torshavn-ii/b71-sandur/3466577/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/finland/kolmonen/njs-ii/malmin-ponnistajat/3489842/', '/matches/2021/07/26/finland/kolmonen/pave/fc-komeetat/3488566/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/france/ligue-2/dijon-football-cote-dor/fc-sochaux-montbeliard/3525214/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/germany/3-liga/sc-freiburg-ii/sv-wehen-1926-taunusstein-ev/3532622/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/grenada/premier-division/carib-hurricane/chantimelle/3501622/', '/matches/2021/07/26/grenada/premier-division/asoms-paradise/hard-rock/3501623/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/urvalsdeild/knattspyrnufelagid-reykjavik/ithrottarfelag-fylkir-reykjavik/3457972/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/4-deild/ka-asvellir/umf-alftanes/3462684/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/u19-league/kadalvikreynirmag-u19/fram--ulfarnir-u19/3469313/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/u19-cup/selfoss--sl-u19/ia--kari-u19/3526551/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/1-deild-women/hk/afturelding-mosfellsbaer/3457490/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/1-deild-women/knattspyrnudeild-fh/augnablik/3457491/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/1-deild-women/vikingur-reykjavik/haukar/3457492/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iceland/1-deild-women/grv/grotta/3457493/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/indonesia/super-liga/bhayangkara-surabaya-utd/pelita-jaya/3514569/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/iraq/iraqi-league/arbil/al-zawraa/3520679/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iraq/iraqi-league/alsinaat-alkahrabaiya/al-shorta/3520681/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iraq/iraqi-league/al-najaf/al-qasim/3520684/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iraq/iraqi-league/kahrba/al-talaba/3520685/', '/matches/2021/07/26/iraq/iraqi-league/al-simawa/al-diwaniya/3520686/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/jamaica/premier-league/waterhouse-fc/tivoli-gardens-fc/3520515/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/kazakhstan/womens-football-championship/tomiris-turan/biik-kazygurt/3498914/', '/matches/2021/07/26/kazakhstan/womens-football-championship/kyzyl-zhar/sdyusshor-8/3498915/', '/matches/2021/07/26/kazakhstan/womens-football-championship/okzhetpes/kyzyl-orda/3498916/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/kenya/premier-league/nairobi-city-stars/bidco-united/3440296/', '/matches/2021/07/26/kenya/premier-league/ulinzi-stars/gor-mahia/3425362/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/libya/premier-league/al-tahaddi/al-hilal/3581894/', '/matches/2021/07/26/libya/premier-league/darnes/al-akhdar/3581895/', '/matches/2021/07/26/libya/premier-league/al-ahli['/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/primera-division/club-de-futbol-monterrey/club-puebla-fc/3533016/', '/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/primera-division/club-tijuana-xoloitzcuintles-de-caliente/club-tigres-de-la-unl/3533017/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/u20-league/tijuana-u20/tigres-uanl-u20/3550364/', '/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/u20-league/cruz-azul-u20/mazatlan-u20/3550365/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/u18-league/cruz-azul-u18/mazatlan-u18/3557977/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/mexico/liga-mx-femenil/mexico-atletico-san-luis/pumas-unam/3542869/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/nicaragua/primera-division/walter-ferreti/real-madriz/3557364/', '/matches/2021/07/26/nicaragua/primera-division/jalapa/deportivo-ocotal/3557365/', '/matches/2021/07/26/nicaragua/primera-division/managua-fc/juventus-fc-managua/3557366/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/norway/nm-cupen-u19/molde-fk-u19/ranheim-u19/3580568/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/paraguay/division-profesional/cerro-porteno/club-libertad/3538214/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/peru/segunda-division/club-deportivo-union-comercio/club-atletico-grau/3502658/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/poland/ekstraklasa/wisla-krakow-ssa/zaglebie-lubin-ssa/3519411/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/portugal/league-cup/vitoria-guimaraes/leixoes/3549466/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/romania/liga-i/cf-chindia-targoviste/sepsi/3536874/', '/matches/2021/07/26/romania/liga-i/u-craiova-1948/fc-dinamo-1948-sa-bucuresti/3536872/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/russia/premier-league/shakhter-volga-olimpiets/fk-petrotrest/3516375/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/russia/lfl/fk-raspadskaya-mezhdurechensk/fk-radian-baykal-irkutsk/3573348/', '/matches/2021/07/28/russia/lfl/fk-astrakhan/uor-dagestan/3505624/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/serbia/super-liga/fk-kolubara-lazarevac/fk-radnik-surdulica/3521256/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/sweden/allsvenskan/varbergs-bois-fc/ildrottsforeningen-kamraterna-goteborg/3445202/', '/matches/2021/07/26/sweden/allsvenskan/orebro-sportklubb-fotboll/allmanna-idrottsklubben/3445203/', '/matches/2021/07/26/sweden/allsvenskan/ostersunds-fk/halmstads-bollklubb/3445204/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/sweden/superettan/goteborgs-atlet---ildrottssallskap/akropolis-if/3444940/', '/matches/2021/07/26/sweden/superettan/norrby-if/vasteras-sk-fk/3444944/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/ukraine/premier-league/fc-vorskla-poltava/dnipro-1/3536537/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/ukraine/persha-liga/alians-lypova-dolyna/metal-kharkiv/3551190/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/ukraine/druha-liga/rubikon/dinaz-vyshhorod/3574023/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls/new-york-city/orlando-city-fc/3481369/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls/new-england-revolution/montreal-impacts/3481373/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls/inter-miami/philadelphia-union/3481371/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls/washington-district-of-columbia-united/new-york-red-bulls/3481370/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls/seattle-sounders-fc/kansas-city-wizards/3481372/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/mls-reserve-league/la-galaxy-ii/oakland-roots/3485114/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/pdl/western-mass-pioneers/carolina-dynamo/3581622/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/pdl/des-moines-menace/usa-portland-timbers-under-23/3581623/']       
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/nisa-independent-cup/california-utd-strikerrs/fc-arizona/3530151/', '/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/nisa-independent-cup/magia/los-angeles-force/3530100/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/national-womens-soccer-league/racing-louisville/washington-spirit/3499690/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/united-states/wpsl/usa-davis-fc/san-francisco-nighthawks/3506548/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/venezuela/primera-division/guaros-de-lara-fc/yaracuyanos-fc/3573336/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/genclerbirligi/fenerbahce-spor-kulubu/3581875/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/trabzonspor/kasimpasa-sk/3547898/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/uc-sampdoria/piacenza-calcio/3568664/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/union-deportiva-las-palmas/wolverhampton-wanderers-fc/3552906/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/crawley-town-football-club/west-ham-united-u23/3526283/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/k-sports/dover-athletic-fc/3564632/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/chelmsford-city-fc/kings-lynn-town-fc/3514003/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/oakland-stompers/el-farolito/3574768/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/oakland-stompers/sonoma-county-sol-/3547644/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/union-sandersdorf/germania-03-kothen/3581919/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/hendon-fc/hampton-and-richmond-borough-fc/3580595/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/winsford-united/mossley-afc/3580596/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/afc-dunstable/biggleswade-united-fc/3581920/', '/matches/2021/07/26/world/club-friendlies/highworth-town-football-club/brimscombe--thrupp/3582397/']
['/matches/2021/07/26/world/florida-cup/everton-football-club/club-deportivo-los-millonarios/3510980/']
```

**Quicker Version:**

```
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}

mainurl = "https://us.soccerway.com"


async def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

allin = []


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for client, n, m in channel:
            params = {
                "block_id": "block_home_matches_31",
                "callback_params": json.dumps({
                    "block_service_id": "home_index_block_homematches",
                    "date": "2021-07-26",
                    "display": "all",
                    "stage-value": n
                }),
                "action": "showMatches",
                "params": json.dumps({
                    "competition_id": m
                })
            }
            r = await client.get(mainurl + '/a/block_home_matches', params=params)
            soup = await get_soup(r.json()['commands'][0]['parameters']['content'])
            res = (x.a['href'] for x in soup.select('td.score-time'))
            allin.extend(res)


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client,  trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        client.headers.update(headers)
        r = await client.get(mainurl)
        soup = await get_soup(r.text)
        goal = ((num, x['id'].split('-', 1)[-1]) for num, x in enumerate(
            soup.select('tr[id^=date_matches]'), start=1))

        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)

        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(100):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for n, m in goal:
                    await sender.send([client, n, m])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        trio.run(main)
        links = map(lambda x: mainurl+x, allin)
        print(list(links))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit('Bye!')
```

> Note: pip install trio httpx

Comment: Hello friend, well... These two links I can recover in my first script, the problem is that the other links are hidden because it is necessary to click on the elements to expand. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to try help me!

Comment: @BrondbyIF you welcome. a quicker version updated.

Comment: What an immense learning experience you are offering me in your increasingly complete and complex answer so that I can study and learn!

All that much I'll thank you will be little, you're a beast (In the good sense of the word)!

Comment: Hello @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη , could you help me in how I could use yesterday's date and tomorrow's date to collect the list of those dates as well? I even created the date model for each option, but it returned an error. Here is the model I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/47ashLy9/1/ ---> If you want me to create a new question with the question for you to answer, just let me know. Thanks in advance!